# How can I write a for loop for this?

Tags: r

I would like to write a for loop for the actions below, data is a df with multiple columns, each column contains a list. I would like to replace all NULL values in each column list with NA so that I can bind all lists into a dataframe. If there's a more efficient way to do this than a for loop I would like to know as well. Thank you.

```
for (i in names(data)){

list1=sapply(data[,1], function(x) ifelse(x == "NULL", NA, x))
list1=as.data.frame(list1)
list2=sapply(data[,2], function(x) ifelse(x == "NULL", NA, x))
list2=as.data.frame(list2)
.
.
.
fulllist=as.data.frame(cbind(list1,list2,....))
fulllist = as.data.frame(t(fulllist))

}
```

Comment: yes I know i need to replace it with i, i just don't know what to do for the other parts...:(

Comment: Please check the solution below

Answer (score 2):

We loop over the columns of the data to find the `list` column ('i1').  Use that index to loop over the columns, then loop over the elements of the `list` and assign those NULL elements to NA

```
i1 <- sapply(data, is.list)
data[i1] <- lapply(data[i1], function(x) {
               i2 <- sapply(x, is.null)
                x[i2] <- NA
                x })
```

Comment: unfortunately that did nothing to my data, lists are nested are values still appear to be NULL.

Answer (score 1):

If you indeed are working with a dataframe, you could perhaps consider not going through listing and recombining into dataframe:

```
purrr::map_df(.x = data, .f = ~ stringr::str_replace(.x, 'NULL', NA_character_))
```

You are inputting a dataframe `data`, applying to each column the function `str_replace` where you replace the character `NULL` with the character version of `NA`. The output is also a dataframe.

Here is an example:

```
library(purrr)
library(stringr)

df <- data.frame(
  X1 = c('A', 'NULL', 'B'),
  X2 = c('NULL', 'C', 'D'),
  X3 = c('E', 'NULL', 'NULL')
)

purrr::map_df(.x = df, .f = ~ stringr::str_replace(.x, 'NULL', NA_character_))
#   X1    X2    X3   
#   <chr> <chr> <chr>
# 1 A     NA    E    
# 2 NA    C     NA   
# 3 B     D     NA
```

Comment: each column is in list format, not vector unfortunately

Comment: May I send you a sample data to try please?